# How to insert string into Date field in Oracle via XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm taking a date in the format of '20010101' from an XML file, and i'm trying to use an XSLT to convert it into a date format to pass into an oracle database. The current XML is this -

```
<expected_arrival_date>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string-length(ASNHeaderFields/ShippedDate)>0">
<xsl:value-of select="concat($seperator, ASNHeaderFields/ShippedDate, 
$seperator)" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($seperator, $currenttime, $seperator)" />
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</expected_arrival_date>
```

But it's just inserting a null value. I can see from testing that the value being passed is 20010101 so i'm not sure why i'm getting the null value each time?

Comment: Sorry, must have been saved from a previous post!

Comment: What is `$seperator` set to?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue that I see in your style sheet is that you're using `>` in your `test` condition.

The `>` character is a reserved character in XML, so instead you should be using:

- `&gt;` (XSLT 1/2)
- `gt` (XSLT 2)